# Is it possible to have aliases in a multi-document YAML stream that span all documents?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

This is what I'm trying to do (code is in Python 3):

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
from print import pprint

yaml_document_with_aliases = """
title: test
choices: &C
  a: one
  b: two
  c: three
---
title: test 2
choices: *C
"""

items = list(yaml.load_all(yaml_document_with_aliases))
```

The result is:

```
ComposerError: found undefined alias 'C'
```

When I'm using a non-document-based YAML file, this works as expected:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
from print import pprint

yaml_nodes_with_aliases = """
-
  title: test
  choices: &C
    a: one
    b: two
    c: three
-
  title: test 2
  choices: *C
"""

items = yaml.load(yaml_nodes_with_aliases)

pprint(items)
```

Result:

```
[{'choices': {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three'}, 'title': 'test'},
 {'choices': {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three'}, 'title': 'test 2'}]
```

(what I wanted to accomplish anyway)

---

Since it's not possible right now, I'm using the following brittle workaround:

```
def yaml_load_all_with_aliases(yaml_text):
    if not yaml_text.startswith('---'):
        yaml_text = '---\n' + yaml_text
    for pat, repl in [('^', '  '), ('^\s*---\s*$', '-'), ('^\s+\.{3}$\n', '')]:
        yaml_text = re.sub(pat, repl, yaml_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    yaml_text = yaml_text.strip()
    return yaml.safe_load(yaml_text)
```

Comment: You should use `safe_load_all()` and `safe_load()` unless you have tagged YAML content in your real files. That won't solve the problem of the anchor not being found, but it will prevent potentially malicious YAML from executing arbitrary code in your program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that:

```
title: test
choices: &C
  a: one
  b: two
  c: three
---
title: test 2
choices: *C
```

is not **a** document, these are two YAML documents in one file. The anchor definition `&C` doesn't carry from one YAML document to another, it can only be used up until the document separator `---`.

If you are willing to have all anchors "carry over" to the following documents in a single YAML stream you can graft a new `compose_document` method on the `Composer` class (i.e. monkey-patch it):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
title: test
choices: &C
  a: one
  b: two
  c: three
---
title: test 2
choices: *C
"""


def my_compose_document(self):
    self.get_event()
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
    self.get_event()
    # this prevents cleaning of anchors between documents in **one stream**
    # self.anchors = {}
    return node

ruamel.yaml.composer.Composer.compose_document = my_compose_document

datas = []
for data in ruamel.yaml.safe_load_all(yaml_str):
    datas.append(data)

datas[0]['choices']['a'] = 1
for data in datas:
    ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout, explicit_start=True)
```

which gives:

```
---
title: test
choices:
  a: 1
  b: two
  c: three
---
title: test 2
choices:
  a: one
  b: two
  c: three
```

Note that this gets you a **copy** of the dict with keys `a`, `b`, and `c`.

(If the key ordering, and preservation of comments is important, use `round_trip_load_all` instead of `safe_load_all`)

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering so quickly :)


Forgive me, I thought I had the terminology right... What do you call that then? A multi-document? And (most importantly) is there no way to carry over alias definition from one document to the next?

Comment: @gschizas The YAML 1.2 talks about documents and streams, where the later can have  multiple (or one or zero) documents. (`safe_`)`load_all` is for iterating over documents. In the normal loader the anchor and alias information is resolved [**and discarded**](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878) as the YAML gets composed into the native data structures. With round-trip loading you might be able to graft this from one documented to another, as in that case the anchor information is not discarded (I'm looking into that, it is not trivial)

Comment: Thanks - I assumed that it was something that I was missing, or something that required much more development than I could handle on my own. For now I have used a stupid and brittle workaround.

Comment: @gschizas after trying a roundabout way I found something that might be an easier solution, unless your alias dict should not just have the same values, but actually be the same dict in memory (i.e. if you change the values on the one after loading, you change the other).

Comment: I wouldn't mind that. In fact, it might even be preferable. I'm just using this dict to construct something else, after loading I treat it as readonly.